What is Numbers 18:14-17 talking about?
I'm reading the NIV. Here is the passage:
14 “Everything in Israel that is devoted[a] to the Lord is yours. 15 The first offspring of every womb, both human and animal, that is offered to the Lord is yours. But you must redeem every firstborn son and every firstborn male of unclean animals. 16 When they are a month old, you must redeem them at the redemption price set at five shekels[b] of silver, according to the sanctuary shekel, which weighs twenty gerahs.
God is talking to the Levites here. What does it mean that the firstborn of humans and animals are offered to the Lord, and that they now belong to the Levites? It's not saying that all firstborn humans and animals belong to the Levites, right? And what does it mean to redeem them for this monetary price?
Thanks!

God told the people of Israel that the first offspring were His.
Exodus 13:3

Then the Lord spoke to Moses, saying: 2 Sanctify unto Me all the firstborn, the firstborn of every womb among the children of Israel, both of man and of beast. It is Mine.

The firstborn belong to God.
Exodus 13

11 “It shall be when the Lord brings you into the land of the Canaanites, just as He swore to you and to your fathers, and shall give it you, 12 that you shall set apart to the Lord the first offspring of every womb and the first offspring of every beast which you have. The males shall be the Lord’s. 13 But every first offspring of a donkey you shall redeem with a lamb. And if you do not redeem it, then you shall break its neck, and all the firstborn of man among your sons you shall redeem.

Note: "and all the firstborn of man among your sons you shall redeem"
God does not want human sacrifice. The firstborn son is to be redeemed - an amount of money was to be given in place of the firstborn son. The point was for God's people to acknowledge that they belong to God.
These instructions are repeated in Numbers along with instructions that the priests and Levites should use the offerings to live upon since they were not given land.
Numbers 18

8 The Lord spoke to Aaron: I have certainly given you the charge of the offerings made to Me, all the hallowed gifts of the children of Israel. To you and to your sons have I given them as a portion, as an ordinance forever.


God Comes FirstThe main point of this (these) ordinance is to remind  the people of God that God has first place in their lives. Not just the "first-born" of man and animal, but the "first-fruits" of all the harvests (the tithes) were to be given back to the LORD (via His priests) to underscore this salient existential fact. (See Proverbs 3:9)
God blesses the congregation of believers with prosperity (economic, political, medical, riches), but the focus is to always be on the Giver and not on the gifts! This practice of giving the first-born was ordained to help insure that this truth stayed in the forefront, and they would maintain that focus. This is the LORD's world, and we are not to forget this amidst our busy, preoccupied lives.
Notice all the firsts in the scriptures: first fruits...first born...first day of the week (resurrection)...first spoils (Jericho)...the LORD, the first (Isaiah 41:4)...first commandment (Matthew 22:37-38)...first from the dead (Acts 26:23)...firstfruits unto God (Revelation 14:4)...first resurrection (Revelation 20:6)...etc.
What was true of the Old Testament, is also true of the New Testament era:

Seek first the Kingdom of God and His righteousness, and all these things shall be added unto you. (Matthew 6:33)

AddendumIn modern Christianity, several churches have a rite of dedication for the firstborn of a married couple. They dedicate their child unto the LORD. Although this is not exactly the same as the Old Testament rite, it does highlight the fact that the families acknowledge God is to be "first" in their lives and in their nuclear family.
